# add specific class to paragraph when div has specific class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a wordpress page in which I generate a content element for each post. To test, I created 4 posts which generate the content elements perfectly. In some cases, there are some images in the post. For this I'm using a wp slider plugin. Sometimes the slider is floated left, sometimes right. And then I have to float the text the other way as the slider.

Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to float the text left, when the image is float to right and the other way around. I'm using jQuery to achieve this. But I'm struggling.

```
if($('.blockcontent div').hasClass('slider-right')){
    $('.blockcontent p').removeClass('pright');
    $('.blockcontent p').addClass('pleft');
}

else if($('.blockcontent div').hasClass('slider-left')){
    $('.blockcontent p').removeClass('pleft');
    $('.blockcontent p').addClass('pright');
}

else{
    $('.blockcontent p').removeClass('pright');
    $('.blockcontent p').removeClass('pleft');
}
```

If the div in class `blockcontent` is float to the right (`class="slider-right"`), the `p` should have a class to float it to the right.

The problem is, that every paragraph float to one direction. The reason is that it's add this class to **every** paragraph, right? But I'm not able to add this class only to this div.

It wouldn't be a problem if I could do it static, but it has to be dynamic.

Is there a trick or can give anyone please give me some hints?

**EDIT:**

Here you can see my HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block">
        <h2>test1</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="blockcontent">
            <p>this is test 1</p><br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <h2>test2</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="blockcontent">
            <p>this is test 2</p><br />
            <div style="max-width: 700px;" class="metaslider metaslider-flex metaslider-21 ml-slider slider-left">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should `$(.blockcontent p)` be `$('.blockcontent p')`?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Don't know why it's not in the question. It is in the source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()` to check the child elements and add the `class`.

Similar to below :

```
$(".blockcontent div").each(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('slider-right')){
      $(this).parent().find("p").removeClass('pright');
      $(this).parent().find("p").addClass('pleft');
    }

  else if($(this).hasClass('slider-left')){
      $(this).parent().find("p").removeClass('pleft');
      $(this).parent().find("p").addClass('pright');
   }
  else{
       $(this).parent().find("p").removeClass('pright');
       $(this).parent().find("p").removeClass('pleft');  
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried it in a similar way. The problem is, class `slider-right` is not a class of `.blockcontent`. Its a class of `.blockcontent div`. But then `$(this).find("p")` won't work anymore because `p` is not child of `.blockcontent div`. I hope you understand my problem :)

Comment: I added the HTML structure, please see my question :)

Comment: Cool use `$(this).parent().find("p")` Else you can use  `.siblings()` api also :)